# How do I get rid of my friends?

Tags: youtube

Youtube keeps giving me the "friends are becoming part of subscriptions" message:

> Friends are now becoming part of subscriptions. Subscribe to your friends to see their activity on your homepage.

I already went through my contacts and removed my not-really-friends that were in there, but the notification keeps coming up. Is there some way I can make Youtube forget my old friends list or stop this notification from coming up? I've got 90 "friends" still in this list so removing them all at once would be great.

Comment: Have you subscribed to your existing contacts?

Comment: Do you use Google+?

Comment: @Dez yes, but I think these are my Youtube friends from before.

Comment: @dnbrv some, but I removed most of these people from my contacts and haven't subscribed to others. I don't know who the rest of these are and I see no option to purge them.